# Necesito enviar la variable cédula en otra función

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, jsp

```
$('#roless select').on('dblclick', function(event) {
    $('#modal-roless').modal('show');
    var cedula=$(this).attr('name');

});
$('#modal-roless').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

            $.ajax({
            url:"usuarios/m-roles.html",
            type:"GET",
            data:{
                cedula:cedula
            },
            success:function(resp){
        $('#modal-roless').html(resp);
            }
        });
})
```

Comment: Cual variable necesitas enviar? que quieres lograr? debes explicar tu pregunta y ser más específico

Comment: necesito enviar la variable cedula para que al abrir el modal se envie en ajax la varible

Comment: estoy abriendo un modal al hacer doble click en un select que contiene un name con un valor

Comment: quitale el **var** a la variable cedula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acceder a una variable desde cualquier función debes declarar esa variable como una variable global. Por otro lado si el disparador de tu función es un `select` no debes asignarle un evento `dblclick` si no un `change` (si quieres un evento `click` mejor cambia el `select` por un botón) y debes añadir el valor a la variable antes de abrir la modal, por lo cual tu código debería de quedar así:

```
<script>
    var cedula = '';

    $('#roless select').on('change', function(event) {
        cedula = $(this).attr('name');
        $('#modal-roless').modal('show');
    });

    $('#modal-roless').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"usuarios/m-roles.html",
            type:"GET",
            data:{
                cedula:cedula
            },
            success:function(resp){
                $('#modal-roless').html(resp);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

**Ejemplo de variable local**

```js
function incio(){
  var dato = 'Hola Mundo';
  console.log(dato);
}

function fin(){
  console.log(dato);
}

incio();
fin();
```

**Explicación:** como puedes ver en este ejemplo la primer función imprime el valor de la variable `dato` pero en la segunda función obtenemos un error debido a que como la variable `dato` fue declarada de forma local en la primer función no es reconocida en la segunda.

---

**Ejemplo de variable global**

```js
var dato = '';

function incio(){
  dato = 'Hola Mundo';
  console.log(dato);
}

function fin(){
  console.log(dato);
}

incio();
fin();
```

**Explicación:** como puedes ver en este otro ejemplo al declarar la variable como global puedo acceder al valor de ella sin problemas desde cualquiera de las dos funciones teniendo en cuenta que es en la primer función donde le asigno su valor.

Comment: ya lo intenté pero no funciona lo que envia es la viable cedula= "" con vacio

Comment: @DanielLimacheSerrano he editado la parte de como debe quedar tu código, puedes revisarla.

Comment: gracias ya resolvi mi problema

Comment: @DanielLimacheSerrano me alegra mucho, te invito a que consideres marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que sea de ayuda a otros desarrolladores de la comunidad que lleguen a tener un problema similar, saludos ! :D

Comment: gracias @Camilo Vasquez